# PAM Module mkhomedir with an already existing home

Tags: permissions, pam, home, ldap

I did set up a PAM authentication towards LDAP. It's all working correctly but I have an issue when I have both a local user and an ldap user with the same name but different UID.

I'm working on RH6 and currently my `system-auth` and `password-auth` are configured in this way:

```
session   required      pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0002
```

My `ssosers` user exists on `ldap`:

```
[root@localhost pam.d]# getent -s ldap passwd ssosers
ssosers:x:20100:1000:ssosers:/home/ssosers:/usr/bin/sh
```

And on `/etc/passwd`:

```
[root@localhost pam.d]# cat /etc/passwd | grep ssosers
ssosers:x:50025:50025::/home/ssosers:/bin/bash
```

My `ssosers` can login with both local passwod and ldap password. Please consider that they have different UID. The problem is when I delete the local user to force the authentication against ldap, the next time `ssosers` will log in, the `pam_mkhomedir.so` fails because the `/home/ssosers` already exists and the user can't join to his home due to lack of permissions:

```
Last login: Mon Feb 19 17:01:00 2018 from 10.212.148.18
Could not chdir to home directory /home/ssosers: Permission denied
-sh: /home/ssosers/.profile: Permission denied
-sh-4.1$
```

Is there a way to change the permissions of the home directory of the `$PAM_USER` if the pam_mkhomedir fails? I would like him to join his old home dir.

**UPDATE**

I came up with an easy solution. Basically run this script in order to look for the user over the LDAP, if I find it I delete the user and renew the UID of the home folder, if I don't find it I delete both the user and the home directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
getent -s ldap passwd $1 > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    userdel $1
    chown -R $1 /home/$1
else
    userdel -r $1
fi
```

But how can I add in the positive case a find based on the OLD UID (looking for other files with the OLD uid)?
By the time I do `userdel $1` the local UID (the old one) is no more resolved. This is the permission of the home directory of `ssosers`'s user after the delete:

```
drwx------   3    50025 oinstall   1024 Feb 19 18:30 ssosers
```

That's why I have to renew the permission of the home with a chown, since the `passwd` in the `nsswitch` points first to `files` and then to `ldap`

Comment: Cool, a -1 without any comments from the typical random user.

Comment: I didn't downvote this question, but it doesn't surprise me that someone did.  If you looked at the man page for `pam_mkhomedir` you would have noticed that it doesn't have any options to do anything like what you want.  More importantly, this isn't really a PAM problem.  It's just a variation of "I want to change the UID of a user" - and the answer is that if you change a user's UID, you **also** have to change the owner of all files & directories belonging to the old UID so that they are owned by new UID.   e.g. `find / -uid OLDUID -exec chown NEWUID {} +`.

Comment: you probably need to do the same for group-ownership of files & dirs if the user's main GID has also changed.

Comment: Hi @cas thank you for answer me. I know the mkhomedir has no options for this but it has a return value of PAM_PERM_DENIED which I think it should handled by a pam_script.so or so. I have no problem on the GID since it's the same. It's just the UID that I want to change.  My question is just not "I want to change the UID of a user" since I would like to authomatize it during a pam authentication when the mkhomedir fails. So I have to handle it on tha pam modules. Do you have any tips on this?

Comment: sorry, no idea. i've never used `pam_script`.   Have you tried reading its docs and writing a script?  At a guess, it would probably need to be done in the auth phase, before session (or at least before `pam_mkhomedir`).   Try doing that and if you run into problems, edit your question with the code you're having trouble with, along with any relevant error output or log entry.

Comment: Me neither. I saw the man page, but if I would like to run it only when the mkhomedir fails, I should refer it in the session and after the mkhomedir. Otherwise use it in the auth and run some checks inside the script, but it's not clear how to pass some variables like $USER, $NEWUSERID, $OLDUSERID etc.

Comment: Personally, I would just avoid the problem entirely by fixing the ownership of all files & dirs owned by users who were originally local users but are now LDAP users.   Sometimes the simplest solution is the best, and almost always the most robust (complicated things tend to be a lot more fragile)

Comment: Yes, since the nsswitch points to `files ldap` I think that we will go with a script that will `userdel <user>` (local UID is resolved here)  and after `chown -R <user> /home/<user>` (ldap UID is resolved here)

Comment: The users may own files outside of their home directories.  In particular, under /tmp and /var/tmp, maybe other locations too.   /tmp is cleared on reboot, but /var/tmp isn't.  try the `find` command in my first comment above (at least for those directories if not the entire fs).

Comment: I updated with the script I'm testing, do you have any tips? Please take note that I can't do it manually looking at the old UID since this process should be run over 500+ servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the user's old UID in a variable before you delete the user.

e.g. here's an improved version of your script that:

- can take multiple username args on the command line
- properly quotes all variables
- has two different methods of fixing ownership - choose 1 only.
- has some very primitive error checking.  needs more.  Try to think of all the things that could possibly go wrong, then think of a way to test for them, and use the `error()` function to abort if necessary.    If you have a colleague who knows your environment that you can show your code to and ask "What am I missing?", "What else could go wrong?" that would be very useful.

It still needs work before I'd consider it safe to use on my systems, but it's good enough for an example.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

error() {
  local ec="$1" ; shift # first arg is the exit code

  # if there are any more args, they are the error message. print to stderr
  [ -n "$*" ] && echo "$@" >&2

  # exit with $ec if $ec is non-zero
  [ "$ec" -ne 0 ] && exit "$ec"
}

for user in "$@" ; do 
  OLDUID=$(getent -s files passwd "$user" | cut -d : -f 3)
  [ -z "$OLDUID" ] && error 1 "user '$user' is not local"

  NEWUID=$(getent -s ldap passwd "$user" | cut -d : -f 3)

  if [ -z "$NEWUID" ] ; then
    # user exists locally but there is no corresponding LDAP user
    # so delete the user and their home dir.  This **definitely** needs
    # more sanity checking to make sure you're not deleting root or some
    # other important account.  Maybe check that [ "$OLDUID" -ge 1000 ]
    # (or 500 or whatever the lowest normal-user uid is on your system)

    userdel -r "$user"

  elif [ "$OLDUID" -ne "$NEWUID" ]; then
    # both local and LDAP user exist.  UIDs are different, so delete the local
    # user and change ownership of their files to the the LDAP uid.

    # Method 1:
    #homedir=$(getent -s files passwd "$user" | cut -d : -f 6)
    #userdel "$user"
    #chown -R "$user" "$homedir"
    #find /tmp /var/tmp -uid "$OLDUID" -exec chown "$NEWUID" {} +

    # Method 2:
    #userdel "$user"
    #find / -uid "$OLDUID" -exec chown "$NEWUID" {} +
  else
    # both exist, delete local user. UIDs are equal, no need to chown anything.

    userdel "$user"
  fi
done
```

---

BTW, as this script handles multiple username args, you may want to use `error 0 ...` rather than `error 1 ...` to just log problems to stderr without aborting, but you'll need to skip to the next username if either OLDUID or NEWUID is empty.

e.g.

```
  OLDUID=$(getent -s files passwd "$user" | cut -d : -f3)
  [ -z "$OLDUID" ] && error 0 "user '$user' is not local" && continue
```

Comment: Thank you cas. No actually I want to delete the user with the homedir if the user is NOT on LDAP, and delete only the user (without the homedire) if the user is ALSO on LDAP.

Comment: @GoingSolo OK, updated the script to do that.

Comment: Thanks @cas we are doing this just on personal user account so there is a whitelist filter before run the script. PS: I can't edit here but you missed a -d in the second lookup.

Comment: fixed it. also got rid of the `-a` in the `elif` test.